# Posting the code from JSFiddle isn't a good edit?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I made [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5664562), where a question did not have any code in it but a JSFiddle link. So, I posted the code from JSFiddle into the question.

It was rejected by two users with:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

and one with:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

I just want to know whether it is a good idea to post the JSFiddle code into the question.

The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590958/javascript-video-overlay-works-in-chrome-but-not-in-firefox).

Answer (score 7):

If you're going to edit code from another source into the question, you have to make it clear in the edit summary *where that code is coming from*. Otherwise, it looks like you're inserting your *own* code, which **is** an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

Try this:

> Inserted code from [source: JSFiddle, comments, etc.] for context

You said this:

> put the code from jsfiddle

That's unclear at best, but it *should* have gotten the point across: the user who marked it as an invalid edit likely wasn't paying attention and just saw a large code insertion, so rejected it.

The two who said it was too minor were likely referring to the fact that there were other issues with the post ("thanks," grammar, capitalization, "Firefox" and "Chrome" being backticked, etc.) that should have been fixed along with the code insertion.

Comment: Editors seem to have such a hard time writing good edit summaries. Considering these people are programmers, I'd hate to have to dig through their source control systems…

Comment: @Cody Gray: Maybe it's because these people *don't* use source control.