# Pending edit copies OP's code as JSFiddle - Should I reject?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

While taking a dive into the review queue, I find a [pending edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11429962) that adds a link to what seems like a JSFiddle of the OP's code.

I feel that JSFiddles should be either posted in answers/comments or by posters themselves, as it is not immediate to verify that the code is the same as the OP's. However, I am unsure if my rejection on the grounds of "causes harm" (stated reason:

> No easy way to verify if JSFiddle code is the same as the OP's - would
>   be better as part of an answer, or even as a comment, to preserve
>   attribution.

) is justified or not. Hence this question: should edits that make (rather largish) fragments of code executable be accepted? If not, what would be the best reject-reason?

(It seems that the [reverse question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270305/posting-the-code-from-jsfiddle-isnt-a-good-edit) has already been asked)

Comment: No, this is a worthless edit. *Maybe* if he had edited in a Stack Snippet or something on this site, but adding a link to an external resource that is redundant with the code already in the question is completely useless.

Comment: @CodyGray that answers the "should it be rejected" - on the other hand, it is not (clear) vandalism, and it provides arguable value in the sense that it allows code to be executed. So what should I list as the reject reason? Should have used a Stack Snippet?

Comment: *"This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."* seems apropos.

Comment: @CodyGray makes sense. Upvoted comment, would also upvote (together with the previous one) as an answer.